# React useState hook and promise response from callout - argument of type ... => void is not assignable to parameter of type SetStateAction<{...}>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to set state on an object. I have a callout that works, but I'm having trouble assigning values from the response of the callout to the properties of the state object. Here is my code:

```
const [customerResponse, setCustomerResponse] = React.useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "", 
    currentPremiumDue: ""
});

function validateInformation() {
    if (validationInfo.policyNumber.trim() !== "" && validationInfo.dateOfBirth.trim() !== "" && checked) {
        const response = CustomerDetailService.getInstance().getCustomerInfo(validationInfo.policyNumber.trim(), validationInfo.dateOfBirth.trim())
        .then((response) => {
            setCustomerResponse((prevCustomerResponse) => {
                prevCustomerResponse.firstName = response.party.person.personNameList[0].firstName
                prevCustomerResponse.lastName = response.party.person.personNameList[0].lastName
                prevCustomerResponse.currentPremiumDue = response.policyDetail.currentPremiumDue
            })
        })
        
    }
}
```

I have already verified that the callout works and returns a proper response. It is what I am doing with the response that is causing an error.

The error is on the argument prevCustomerResponse for the arrow function in setCustomerResponse. The error message is as follows:

```
Argument of type '(prevCustomerResponse: { firstName: string; lastName: string; currentPremiumDue: string; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ firstName: string; lastName: string; currentPremiumDue: string; }>'.
Type '(prevCustomerResponse: { firstName: string; lastName: string; currentPremiumDue: string; }) => void' is not assignable to type '(prevState: { firstName: string; lastName: string; currentPremiumDue: string; }) => { firstName: string; lastName: string; currentPremiumDue: string; }'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; currentPremiumDue: string; }'.ts(2345)
(parameter) prevCustomerResponse: {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    currentPremiumDue: string;
}
```

I've searched for an explanation but found none that addresses this particular scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ***mutating*** the `customerResponse` state ***and not*** returning a new state value, e.g. the void return.

```js
function validateInformation() {
  if (validationInfo.policyNumber.trim() !== "" &&
    validationInfo.dateOfBirth.trim() !== "" &&
    checked
  ) {
    const response = CustomerDetailService.getInstance()
      .getCustomerInfo(
        validationInfo.policyNumber.trim(),
        validationInfo.dateOfBirth.trim()
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setCustomerResponse((prevCustomerResponse) => {
          prevCustomerResponse.firstName =         // <-- mutation!
            response.party.person.personNameList[0].firstName
          prevCustomerResponse.lastName =          // <-- mutation!
            response.party.person.personNameList[0].lastName
          prevCustomerResponse.currentPremiumDue = // <-- mutation!
            response.policyDetail.currentPremiumDue

          // <-- missing return!
        })
      })
  }
}
```

It should instead shallow copy the current state *then* mutate/overwrite properties and return the next state value.

Example:

```js
function validateInformation() {
  if (validationInfo.policyNumber.trim() !== "" &&
    validationInfo.dateOfBirth.trim() !== "" &&
    checked
  ) {
    const response = CustomerDetailService.getInstance()
      .getCustomerInfo(
        validationInfo.policyNumber.trim(),
        validationInfo.dateOfBirth.trim()
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const {
          party: {
            person: [{ firstName, lastName }]
          },
          policyDetail: { currentPremiumDue }
        } = response;

        setCustomerResponse(customerResponse => ({ // <-- new object reference
          ...customerResponse, // <-- shallow copy current state
          firstName,           // <-- overwrite properties
          lastName,
          currentPremiumDue,
        }));
      });
  }
}
```

or

```js
async function validateInformation() {
  if (validationInfo.policyNumber.trim() !== "" &&
    validationInfo.dateOfBirth.trim() !== "" &&
    checked
  ) {
    const response = await CustomerDetailService.getInstance()
      .getCustomerInfo(
        validationInfo.policyNumber.trim(),
        validationInfo.dateOfBirth.trim()
      );

    const {
      party: {
        person: [{ firstName, lastName }]
      },
      policyDetail: { currentPremiumDue }
    } = response;

    setCustomerResponse(customerResponse => ({
      ...customerResponse,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      currentPremiumDue,
    }));
  }
}
```